# How to apply CSS selector on Select Option Child

Tags: html, css

I only want to apply css selector on select option child value. I have an id applied on the selector. Now I want to apply different css on child 1 child 2 and so on so forth

```
<select name="options[81]" id="select_81" class=" required-entry product-custom-option">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="229" price="0">ariel </option>
    <option value="230" price="0">times new roman </option>
</select>
```

now I have tried these selectors but nothing works

```
select#select_81.required-entry.product.custom-option:nth-child(2){
    font-family:'Arial';
}

select#select_81.required-entry.product.custom-option:nth-child(3){
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:800;
}

#select_81.required-entry.product.custom-option:nth-child(3){
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:800;
}

#select_81:nth-child(3){
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:800;
}

select#select_81option:nth-child(2), option:nth-child(3) {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

How can we do this by using CSS?

Comment: simply just `#select_81 option{}` or similar. You could use the `nth-of-type` selector too, to select specific ones. That being said, option drop downs can't really be styled too much. You usuially have to apply the style to the `<select>`.

Comment: i want to apply different css on different child please read the question again

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/7c7q2ghe/

Comment: I think we can remove the `jquery` and `javascript` tags from this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're doing `.product.custom-option` instead of `.product-custom-option`.

But your code doesn't need to be that complicated.

To answer your question, to select the nth option, use the `:nth-child()` selector:

```
select#select_81 option:nth-child(1) {}
select#select_81 option:nth-child(2) {}
select#select_81 option:nth-child(3) {}
select#select_81 option:nth-child(4) {}
select#select_81 option:nth-child(5) {}
...
```

But you can't really style the options inside a select dropdown; the system normally gives it default styling that you can't change.

Comment: oh now why and how we can change that?

Comment: @geekone You can't change the styling of the option values. However, using `-webkit-appearance: none` will remove all default browser stylings **on the select dropdown only**. See https://jsfiddle.net/ans5zhmz/.

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers don't let you do very much styling on the default `<select>` dropdown menus. That's why libraries like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) exist.

More info about styling dropdown menus: https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/